# Why isn't withContext resuming to the original dispatcher on completion?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I'm writing a suspending function that should run on a specific dispatcher. It may be called from any dispatcher, so it should resume to the original dispatcher when returning.

[`withContext`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/with-context.html) should help, since it states that:

> This function uses dispatcher from the new context, shifting execution
> of the block into the different thread if a new dispatcher is
> specified, and back to the original dispatcher when it completes.

Here is a basic test:

```
import kotlinx.coroutines.Dispatchers
import kotlinx.coroutines.delay
import kotlinx.coroutines.runBlocking
import kotlinx.coroutines.test.TestCoroutineDispatcher
import kotlinx.coroutines.test.setMain
import kotlinx.coroutines.withContext

fun log(message: String = "") {
    println("[${Thread.currentThread().name}] $message")
}

suspend fun test9Odd(x: Int): Boolean {
    return withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        log("test9Odd for x = $x...")
        delay(250)
        x and 1 == 1
    }
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    // setting Dispatcher.Main for the test:
    val x = TestCoroutineDispatcher()
    x.runCurrent()
    Dispatchers.setMain(x)

    runBlocking {
        withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
            log("test9")
            for (x in listOf(8, 97, 108)) {
                val result = test9Odd(x)
                log("Is $x odd? ${if (result) "yes" else "no"}")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What I observe is contradictory to the statement above, the context switches but is not resumed when returning, it keeps running on `worker-1`:

```
    [main] test9
    [DefaultDispatcher-worker-1] test9Odd for x = 8...
    [DefaultDispatcher-worker-1] Is 8 odd? no
    [DefaultDispatcher-worker-1] test9Odd for x = 97...
    [DefaultDispatcher-worker-1] Is 97 odd? yes
    [DefaultDispatcher-worker-1] test9Odd for x = 108...
    [DefaultDispatcher-worker-1] Is 108 odd? no
```

My question is: **Why isn't the code in the `main()` function running back on the main thread after the 1st call?**

Note that if I remove the `withContext` in the main function, *then* it switches back to the main thread. If I replace `withContext` with `launch` however, it doesn't change this issue.

Comment: Which coroutines platform-specific dependency do you have in this project, e.g. `kotlinx-coroutines-swing`, `kotlinx-coroutines-android`, `kotlinx-coroutines-javafx`? The main dispatcher is invalid if you aren't using one of these.

Comment: I can't reproduce your incorrect output. It switches dispatchers back and forth as expected. I tried it using `kotlinx-coroutines-swing` and also in a unit test where I set my own single-threaded dispatchers as Main.

Comment: @Tenfour04 Good point! I'm using those, indeed, but I set the main context as shown above (I updated the question). Is that incorrect?

Comment: Even if I put a `withContext(Dispatchers.Main)` around the log call in main, it still remains on the IO worker... this is mostly confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know that coroutine testing has been up until recently described as "flaky" and difficult to set up in a way that gives expected results.

They recently overhauled the test library, and TestCoroutineDispatcher is deprecated.

The following test works for me:

```
class Tests {

    @Before
    fun before() {
        Dispatchers.setMain(StandardTestDispatcher())
    }

    @Test
    fun `switch between dispatchers`() = runTest {
        withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
            log("test9")
            for (x in listOf(8, 97, 108)) {
                val result = test9Odd(x)
                log("Is $x odd? ${if (result) "yes" else "no"}")
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Output:

```
[Test worker @coroutine#1] test9
[DefaultDispatcher-worker-1] test9Odd for x = 8...
[Test worker @coroutine#1] Is 8 odd? no
[DefaultDispatcher-worker-1] test9Odd for x = 97...
[Test worker @coroutine#1] Is 97 odd? yes
[DefaultDispatcher-worker-1] test9Odd for x = 108...
[Test worker @coroutine#1] Is 108 odd? no
```

This also works:

```
    fun before() {
        Dispatchers.setMain(newSingleThreadContext("main"))
    }
```

Running it outside a test like this works, too:

```
fun main() {
    Dispatchers.setMain(newSingleThreadContext("main"))
    runBlocking {
        withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
            log("test9")
            for (x in listOf(8, 97, 108)) {
                val result = test9Odd(x)
                log("Is $x odd? ${if (result) "yes" else "no"}")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's interesting. Before reading this I switched my dependencies from 1.5.2 to 1.6.0 and I saw that `TestCoroutineDispatcher` had been deprecated. But if I'm using the `StandardTestDispatcher` as in your first example, my code just hangs (and it is annotated as experimental). The 2nd example with `newSingleThreadContext` works, though. Thanks!